# long table's and figure's captions

Tags: tables, captions

How can I make the table and figure captions aligned in the list of tables or list of figures
, my problem is that the list of figures and list of tables are going outside the page margins.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
% the table caption is long when it added to the list of tables.
\begin{table}%[position specifier]
 \centering
   \caption{Comparison with "Indirect Ident." method with a white noise disturbance}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |l |}\hline
 method& criterion& 25dB & 15dB & 10dB \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does the document posted actually show the problem you're having? When I compile it, it wraps the caption in the list of tables correctly.  Maybe you have a long technical word in the caption that TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate properly?

Comment: Actually with me, it does not wrap the caption in the list of tables correctly. But I found another solution by using a small caption to appear in the list of tables: \caption [small caption] { long caption}. This is not the suitable solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using package `hyperref` with a driver that does not support links that breaks across lines (e.g. `dvips`), then option `linktocpage` helps. It makes the page number to a link and removes the unbreakable link from the title.

Example file with David Carlisle's [quoting fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120606/16967):

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  linktocpage,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\begin{table}%[position specifier]
 \centering
   \caption{Comparison with ``Indirect Ident.'' method with a white noise
 disturbance}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |l |}\hline
 method& criterion& 25dB & 15dB & 10dB \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This works correctly with me. Thank you very much.